# swipe refresh android by condition

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

i have swipe refresh that refresh my webview content, and i have 1 issue
sometimes i don't need for refreshing for exaple when my location is /test or /norefresh, and how i can exclude swipe refresh by my condition (when location have some url's) ?

```
      //swipe refresh
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
           mywebview.reload();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Simply add an `if` statement inside `onRefresh`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the method `setEnabled()` on `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
The logic to detect page change is different if you use `WebViewClient` or `WebChromeClient`.

For `WebViewClient` for example:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        swipeLayout.setEnabled(!url.contains("/test") && !url.contains("norefresh/"));
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
```